# Java passing function to method

Tags: java, function

I'm trying to pass a Function to the method. Problem is that I cannot make it work without repeating the same argument.

```
 public void addCartProduct(String cartId, long productId) {
        updateCartProducts(cartId, productCartDto -> productCartDto.addProduct(show(productId)));
    }

    public void removeCartProduct(String cartId, long productId) {
        updateCartProducts(cartId, productCartDto -> productCartDto.removeProduct(show(productId)));
    }

    private void updateCartProducts(String cartId, Function<ProductCartDto,ProductCartDto> processCart){
        productCartRepository.showCart(cartId)
                .map(processCart)
                .map(productCartDto -> productCartRepository.updateCart(cartId, productCartDto))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoResultException("Cannot find cart ID: " + cartId));
    }
```

EDIT: add show method

```
public ProductBasicDto show(Long productId) {
        return productRepository
                .findOptionalById(productId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoResultException("Cannot find product ID: " + productId));
    }
```

Here method show() is redundant. Is there any possibility to make updateCartProducts responsible for this method? I cannot make any changes in existing classes. The difference is that first one adds product and the second removes

Comment: You haven't shown the `show` method

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to improve here as both addProduct and removeProduct take something returned by the show method

Comment: ahh sorry guys, I added show method. And also add/remove methods returns ProductCartDto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there is nothing wrong with your code. If you want to get rid of the `show` method call in those two methods, you can move that into the `updateCartProducts` method and replace the `Function` with a `BiFunction` that takes a `ProductCartDto` and a `ProductBasicDto` and produces a `ProductCartDto`.

```
public void addCartProduct(String cartId, long productId) {
    updateCartProducts(cartId, (productCartDto, productBasicDto) -> productCartDto.addProduct(productBasicDto));
}

public void removeCartProduct(String cartId, long productId) {
    updateCartProducts(cartId, (productCartDto, productBasicDto) -> productCartDto.removeProduct(productBasicDto));
}

private void updateCartProducts(String cartId, BiFunction<ProductCartDto, ProductBasicDto, ProductCartDto> processCart){
    //The code from show method
    ProductBasicDto productBasicDto = productRepository
            .findOptionalById(productId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoResultException("Cannot find product ID: " + productId));

    productCartRepository.showCart(cartId)
            .map(processCartDto -> processCart.apply(processCartDto, productBasicDto))
            .map(productCartDto -> productCartRepository.updateCart(cartId, productCartDto))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoResultException("Cannot find cart ID: " + cartId));
}
```